# how to get share point list data in angular using MSAL login token

Tags: angular, sharepoint, msal-angular

I added the scope of msal still able to login to the system but get unauthorized exception while access the SharePoint list endpoint

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To help you better, can you share more information and code on this issue?